# Using for/if to keep count in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm attempting to create a function that finds how many times an item occurs in a function. I have the code below, but it ends up counting all the items in the list(6), not just the one i want( in this case 1). I know i'm not returning anything, the print is mainly for me to see what answer I get.

```
def count(sequence, item):
    found = 0
    for i in sequence:
        if item in sequence:
            found = found + 1
    print found

count([1,2,1,2,4,5], 1)
```

Comment: It should be `if item == i`. print `i` also on each iteration. You probably will understand why you should check against `i` that way.

Comment: Thanks! Can you tell me why i get 6 when i run as-is? Item in sequence is not found 6 times.

Comment: Because `item` is always in `sequence`. So for every iteration, your code gets into `if` and increments `found`.

Comment: Ok, makes sense. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 def count(sequence, item):
        found = 0
        for i in sequence:
            if i == item:
                found = found + 1
        print found

    count([1,2,1,2,4,5], 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to compare element from `sequence` with `item`

```
if i == item:
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you realize that this method already exists?

```
return sequence.count(item)
```

For instance, we get a value of 2 from

```
my_list = [1,2,1,2,4,5]
print my_list.count(1)
```

Okay, so you want something harder-headed.  :-)  How about this?

```
return len([i for i in sequence if i == item])
```

Comment: This is specifically a method of lists, tuples, and strings, not sequences in general. Good answer though

Answer (score 0):

You could use `sum` and a comprehension

```
def count(haystack, needle):
    return sum(el==needle for el in haystack)
```

This will work for any sequence you can iterate over.

```
>>> s = {"a": None, "b": None, "c": None}
>>> count(s, "a")  # why are you counting a dict? You so crazy....
1
```

This works because `True` can be coerced to the integer `1`. Summing a sequence of booleans results in the count of `True`s in the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, python has an awesome Counter class that will do this for you.

```
from collections import Counter
someList = [1,2,1,2,4,5]
allCounts = Counter(someList) 
print allCounts[1]
print allCounts
```

Answer (score -2):

Python lists [support this natively](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)

```
>>> my_list = [1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 5]
>>> print my_list.count(1)
2
```